Target class [admin] does not exist laravel 11
Having problem with Laravel 11. Simple website is working fine. But when I access admin panel I get this error after logging in .when ever i access admin/dashboard i get the error
"PHP 8.3.6 11.6.0
Target class [admin] does not exist."
App\Http\Kernel.php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\CheckDisabled::class,
            \UxWeb\SweetAlert\ConvertMessagesIntoSweetAlert::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],

        'super_admin' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSuperAdmin::class,
        ],

        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdmin::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdmin::class,
        'super_admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSuperAdmin::class,
        'sweetalert' => \UxWeb\SweetAlert\ConvertMessagesIntoSweetAlert::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}

web.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\EstimateController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ConnectionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\BeamInventoryController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController;

Route::get('/test', [HomeController::class, 'testRoute']);

// Home Routes...
// Route::get('', [HomeController::class, 'index']);

Route::redirect('/', '/home');
Route::get('/welcome', [HomeController::class, 'welcome']);
Route::get('/info', [HomeController::class, 'info']);
Route::get('/test', [HomeController::class, 'testRoute']);
Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/help', [HomeController::class, 'help']);
Route::get('/file-names', [HomeController::class, 'insertFileName']);
Route::get('/getCloudFileNames', [HomeController::class, 'getUserFileNames']);

// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'showLinkRequestForm'])->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'sendResetLinkEmail'])->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'showResetForm'])->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'reset'])->name('password.update');

// Estimate Routes...
Route::post('openLocalFile', [EstimateController::class, 'openLocalFile']);
Route::post('/openCloudFile', [EstimateController::class, 'openCloudFile']);
Route::post('/checkCloudFileExists', [EstimateController::class, 'checkCloudFileExists']);
Route::post('/deleteCloudFile', [EstimateController::class, 'deleteCloudFile']);
Route::post('/saveEstimateData', [EstimateController::class, 'saveEstimate']);
Route::post('/importBofmData', [EstimateController::class, 'importBofmData']);
Route::post('/saveBofMData', [EstimateController::class, 'saveBofM']);
Route::post('/downloadEstimateData', [EstimateController::class, 'downloadEstimateData']);
Route::post('/downloadBofMData', [EstimateController::class, 'downloadBofMData']);
Route::post('/downloadEstimateData', [EstimateController::class, 'downloadEstimateData']);
Route::post('/downloadBofMData', [EstimateController::class, 'downloadBofMData']);

// CatalogController Routes...
Route::get('/catalog-materials', [CatalogController::class, 'getCatalogMaterials']);
Route::get('/catalogs-with-materials', [CatalogController::class, 'getCatalogsWithMaterials']);
Route::post('/update-catalog-materials', [CatalogController::class, 'updateCatalogMaterials']);
Route::get('/catalog-groups', [CatalogController::class, 'getCatalogGroups']);
Route::post('/store-catalog-groups', [CatalogController::class, 'storeCatalogGroups']);
Route::put('/update-catalog-groups/{id}', [CatalogController::class, 'updateCatalogGroups']);
Route::delete('/delete-catalog-groups/{id}', [CatalogController::class, 'destroyCatalogGroups']);
Route::get('/catalogs', [CatalogController::class, 'getCatalogs']);
Route::post('/store-catalogs', [CatalogController::class, 'storeCatalogs']);
Route::put('/update-catalogs/{id}', [CatalogController::class, 'updateCatalogs']);
Route::delete('/delete-catalogs/{id}', [CatalogController::class, 'destroyCatalogs']);
Route::get('/shop-costs', [CatalogController::class, 'getShopCosts']);
Route::post('/update-shop-costs', [CatalogController::class, 'updateShopCosts']);

// ConnectionController Routes...
Route::get('/connections', [ConnectionController::class, 'getConnections']);
Route::post('/store-connections', [ConnectionController::class, 'storeConnections']);
Route::put('/update-connections/{id}', [ConnectionController::class, 'updateConnections']);
Route::delete('/delete-connections/{id}', [ConnectionController::class, 'destroyConnections']);
Route::get('/connection-groups', [ConnectionController::class, 'getConnectionGroups']);
Route::post('/store-connection-groups', [ConnectionController::class, 'storeConnectionGroups']);
Route::put('/update-connection-groups/{id}', [ConnectionController::class, 'updateConnectionGroups']);
Route::delete('/delete-connection-groups/{id}', [ConnectionController::class, 'destroyConnectionGroups']);
Route::get('/connection-groups-with-types', [ConnectionController::class, 'getConnectionGroupsWithTypes']);
Route::post('/update-connection-types', [ConnectionController::class, 'updateConnectionTypes']);
Route::post('/upload-image', [ConnectionController::class, 'uploadimage']);

// BeamInventoryController Routes...
Route::resource('beam-inventory', BeamInventoryController::class);
Route::get('download-text', [BeamInventoryController::class, 'downloadText']);

// User Profile Routes
Route::get('/profile', [UserController::class, 'showProfile'])->name('user.profile');
Route::post('/change-password', [UserController::class, 'changePassword'])->name('user.password');

// Admin Routes
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->name('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');

    // Organizations and Users routes
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'super_admin'], function () {
        Route::get('organizations', [UserController::class, 'getOrganizations'])->name('organizations');
        Route::get('organizations/create', [UserController::class, 'showOrganizationCreate'])->name('organizations.create');
        Route::post('organizations/create', [UserController::class, 'storeOrganizationCreate'])->name('organizations.create');
        Route::get('organizations/{id}/edit', [UserController::class, 'showOrganizationEdit'])->name('organizations.edit');
        Route::put('organizations/{id}/edit', [UserController::class, 'updateOrganizationEdit'])->name('organizations.update');
        Route::delete('organizations/{id}/delete-data', [UserController::class, 'deleteOrganizationDataRequest'])->name('organizations.delete-data');
        Route::delete('organizations/{id}/delete', [UserController::class, 'deleteOrganizationAndData'])->name('organizations.delete');
        Route::put('organizations/{id}/restore', [UserController::class, 'restoreOrganizationAndData'])->name('organizations.restore');
    });

    Route::get('organizations/{id}/users', [UserController::class, 'getOrganizationUsers'])->name('organizations.users');
    Route::get('organizations/{id}/users/create', [UserController::class, 'showOrganizationUserCreate'])->name('organizations.users.create');
    Route::post('organizations/{id}/users/create', [UserController::class, 'storeOrganizationUserCreate'])->name('organizations.users.create');
    Route::get('organizations/{id}/users/{userId}/edit', [UserController::class, 'showOrganizationUserEdit'])->name('organizations.users.edit');
    Route::put('organizations/{id}/users/{userId}/edit', [UserController::class, 'updateOrganizationUserEdit'])->name('organizations.users.update');
    Route::get('organizations/{id}/users/{userId}', [UserController::class, 'showOrganizationUserView'])->name('organizations.users.view');
    Route::delete('organizations/{id}/users/{userId}/delete', [UserController::class, 'userDelete'])->name('organizations.users.delete');
    Route::get('organizations/checkBeforeAddingDefaultData', [UserController::class, 'checkBeforeAddingDefaultData'])->name('organizations.checkBeforeAddingData');
});


can anyone help me solve this?
I have tried suggestions online but nothing is working

your route file doesn't show a middleware applied to that route ... also you shouldn't have a group and a middleware with the same alias ... the admin middleware is a single middleware it doesn't belong in the middleware group section

also super_admin shouldn't be a group, you should only be applying that one middleware when needed ... that entire route file has the web group applied already

you set "Admin" namespace to all admin routes but your controllers is not in "Admin" namespace , remove namespace('Admin') from admin routes to fix this.
Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function () {
  // .. routes
});

